# Is it a good idea to have Launcher Activity implement LocationListener in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-activity, location

I am creating an Android application that has a single Launcher - MainActivity and a Preference Activity.

I was wondering if it was a good idea to have the Launcher activity implement LocationListener or if this was not such a good idea.

Some links suggest that it should be a service, but is that really necessary?

Comment: I would suggest to put the listener in a separate class, which to implement the LocationListener. Then use the class as you want.

Comment: So just create a separate class and instantiate it in the activity?
Any particular reason for this other than the obvious separation of modules?
As in, any performance benefits?

Comment: Well, there are sereal keypoints to explain before I can answer you that. First the difference between the `implements` and `extends` -> In brief: if you implement then you're making a "copy" of the implemented class, by declaring an "abstract" specification if the implemented class. If you're extending, you're adding to the functionnality of the extended class. That being said, in your case if you implement the `LocationListener`, you'll be working only on that part, but if you put it inside a separate class (which implements it) and you instantiate it, you're actually extending it .. follows

Comment: I don't see any major performance benefits by doing this (except of course the separation of modules, which is not considered as such) and I think that the same thing can be obtained if you just put `extends` instead of `implements`.

Comment: LocationListener is an Interface, not an abstract class - therefore it must be Implemented. I guess you're saying - putting it in a separate class and instantiating it in the main activity amounts to extending...? How?

Comment: "Extending" being said with quotation :) Because you're instantiating it in the main class - thus just using it and expanding it probably or implementing some other class.

Comment: Shall I post an Answer on that?